# Excel - Line chart from date and time

Tags: excel, date, charts, linechart

How can I make line chart from this data?

- Two lines
- X values = time
- Y valies = number

This is just small sample of data (I have more than 30 day).

[image]

(I use Excel 2016)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your X-axis is the first column and your Y axis is your 2, 3, 4, etc column
2. Highlight you data that you want to work with, minimum two column.
3. Find your Insert Ribbon
4. Select Insert Chart about halfway across and and make sure you select the line one.  (Personally I would use and XY scatter plot with lines)

In your case where you have X, Y , X, Y as the sequence of your column, I would edit your data series afterwards to eliminate the series which are really your second X values.  Then go to your subsequent Y values, edit their series, and select a new X series for each.

Its usually much easier if you place all your X data in one column, and each Y series in its own column making sure it lines up with the appropriate X data.